# How to make extra validation in Spring Security login form?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I wonder how to make extra validation on login form before it will be processed by Spring Security. I'm thinking about some LoginController, LoginForm bean, but i don't know how to combine it together, how to configure it to work. My "visions" below. I've searched for some examples how to do that in Spring Security but can't find. Anybody helps with that ?

LoginForm bean:

```
public class LoginForm {
    private String j_username;
    private String j_password;
    @NotEmpty
    private Boolean acceptTerms;

    public String getJ_password() {
        return j_password;
    }

    public String getJ_username() {
        return j_username;
    }

    public void setJ_password(String j_password) {
        this.j_password = j_password;
    }

    public void setJ_username(String j_username) {
        this.j_username = j_username;
    }

    public Boolean getAcceptTerms() {
        return acceptTerms;
    }

    public void setAcceptTerms(Boolean accept) {
        this.acceptTerms = acceptTerms;
    }
}
```

Form:

```
<c:url value="/login" var="secureUrl"/>
<form:form id="jf" commandName="loginForm" action="${secureUrl}" method="post">
   <form:input path="j_username"/>
   <form:input path="j_password"/>
   <form:checkbox path="acceptTerms"/>
</form>
```

LoginController:

```
@Controller
class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String logging(@ModelAttribute @Valid LoginForm loginForm) {
                ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView signInPage(
                    @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
                    @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) 
{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    //Initially when you hit on login url then error and logout both null
    if (error != null) {
        mav.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
    }

    if (logout != null) {
        mav.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
    }
    mav.setViewName("login/login.jsp");
}
```

Now if in case login become uncessful then it will again hit this URL with error append in its URL as in spring security file you set the failure URL. Spring security file:

```
<security:form-login
    authentication-failure-url="/login?error=1"
/>
```

Then your URL becomes `url/login?error=1`. Then automatically `signInPage` method will call and with some error value. Now error is not null and you can set any string corresponding to url and we can show on jsp using these following tags:

```
<c:if test="${not empty error}">
    <div class="error">${error}</div>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could subclass UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html

You could override the attemptAuthentication() method, have it call super.attemptAuthentication(), and if that returns a non-null Authentication object, perform your additional work (to see if the user checked the box).

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html#attemptAuthentication(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)

The docs for how to specify your customer filter are here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-custom-filters

Answer (score 1):

Just adding more information on top of @sdouglass comment.

On the filter you'll not have access to the form for binding purposes.

I managed to get it with default validation by doing the following.

https://gist.github.com/3137040