# Spring security perform validations for custom login form

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to do some validations on the login form before calling the authenticationManager for authentication. Have been able to achieve it with help from one existing post - [How to make extra validation in Spring Security login form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025614/how-to-make-extra-validation-in-spring-security-login-form/12929497#12929497)

Could someone please suggest me whether I am following the correct approach or missing out something? Particularly, I was not very clear as to how to show the error messages. 
In the filter I use validator to perform validations on the login field and in case there are errors, I throw an Exception (which extends AuthenticationException) and encapsulate the Errors object. A getErrors() method is provided to the exception class to retrieve the errors.

Since in case of any authentication exception, the failure handler stores the exception in the session, so in my controller, I check for the exception stored in the session and if the exception is there, fill the binding result with the errors object retrieved from the my custom exception (after checking runtime instance of AuthenticationException)

The following are my code snaps -

LoginFilter class

```
public class UsernamePasswordLoginAuthenticationFilter extends
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    private Validator loginValidator;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#attemptAuthentication(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
     */
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

        Login login = new Login();
        login.setUserId(request.getParameter("userId"));
        login.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
        Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(login, "login");
        loginValidator.validate(login, errors);
        if(errors.hasErrors()) {
            throw new LoginAuthenticationValidationException("Authentication Validation Failure", errors);
        }
        return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(@ModelAttribute("login") Login login, BindingResult result,  HttpServletRequest request) {

        AuthenticationException excp = (AuthenticationException)
                request.getSession().getAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
        if(excp != null) {
            if (excp instanceof LoginAuthenticationValidationException) {
                LoginAuthenticationValidationException loginExcp = (LoginAuthenticationValidationException) excp;
                result.addAllErrors(loginExcp.getErrors());
            }
        }
        return "login";
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public void initializeForm(ModelMap map) {
        map.put("login", new Login());
    }
```

This part in the controller to check for the instance of the Exception and then taking out the Errors object, does not look a clean approach. I am not sure whether this is the only way to handle it or someone has approached it in any other way? Please provide your suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want/need to validate login input? Either the credentials are good, or they are not. Seems pretty self-validating...

Comment: Along the same lines, isn't it also the case that you don't want to validate login credentials beyond success or failure on login attempt as you are giving a possible attacker more information than is needed?

Answer (score 1):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView signInPage(
    @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
    @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        //Initially when you hit on login url then error and logout both null
        if (error != null) {
            mav.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            mav.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
        }
        mav.setViewName("login/login.jsp");
}
```

Now if in case login become unsuccessfull then it will again hit this url with error append in its url as in spring security file you set the failure url.
     Spring security file: `-authentication-failure-url="/login?error=1"`
    Then your URl become `url/login?error=1`
    Then automatically signInPage method will call and with some error value.Now error is not null and you can set any string corresponding to url and we can show on jsp using these following tags:-

```
<c:if test="${not empty error}">
   <div class="error">${error}</div>
</c:if>
```