# springframework 'form' tag + spring security auth

Tags: spring, spring-security, jsp-tags

What I want. I want do spring security auth by springframework tag 'form'.
Example

```
<!-- JSP -->
<form:form action="login" commandName="?" >
 <form:errors path="lastError" ></form:errors>
 <form:input path="j_username" />
 <form:password path="j_password" />
 <form:button value="submit" name="submit" />
</form:form>

<!-- security-context.xml -->
<http use-expressions="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/client/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
  <form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login"
    authentication-failure-handler-ref="authHandler" />
  <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" />
</http>
```

What should be instead of "?" in form commandName or how can I do this wily action?
Thanx for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a Loginbean in the commandName that contains the j_username and j_password.

[How to make extra validation in Spring Security login form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025614/how-to-make-extra-validation-in-spring-security-login-form)